# anyDefinedFunction.caller is null, but why Math.anyMathFunction.caller is throwing error?

Tags: javascript

While accessing the `caller` property of any `Math` functions(sin,cos,..) results in the following error.

> Uncaught TypeError: 'caller' and 'arguments' are restricted function
>   properties and cannot be accessed in this context.

But, invoking the same property over other functions like `window.alert` or any user defined functions returns `null`.

```
Math.sin.caller // ERROR
window.alert.caller // null
```

What is the reason behind this behavior? What is the purpose of this restriction?

Answer (score 0):

`Math.sin` is a strict function, while `window.alert` isn't.
You can see the same in the code below:

```
function f() {
    'use strict';
  alert( 'hi' );
}

function g() {
  alert( 'hi' );
}

console.log(g.caller) // null
console.log(f.caller) // null
```

Comment: Nope, Math.sin function is using strict mode in its definition. That is why the error is raising. But why didn't the other functions like window.alert define in a strict mode?

Comment: fixed, thanks.
didn't find a good answer for your question, interesting!